# Android: How to run android service forever in a real device?

Tags: android

I have created an activity which gives user location and this information is send to server using web service.Till this, project runs successfully. But I want to run this activity as a service, so i have created Service and copied the activity code and paste it into service code. But it doesnt work?? I have research regarding this but cant figure it out.

```
GPSTracker.java

package com.example.meragps;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;


public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener 
{


String imei="";
String simSerialNumber="";
String stAdd="";
String currentTime="";
String resultData="";


private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetCurrentLocation";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetCurrentLocation";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://"my static ip"/GPSTracker/Service1.asmx";


private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

 // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1000; // 1000 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 20; // 20 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;






public GPSTracker(Context context) 
{
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();




}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
  //TODO do something useful
    gpsTraking();
    passing();

  return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

public Location getLocation() 
    {

    try 
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) 
    {
            // no network provider is enabled
    } 
        else 
    {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) 
    {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) 
    {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) 
    {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    }
    }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) 
    {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) 
    {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) 
    {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }

    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
    }


public void gpsTraking()
{
      // create class object


    // check if GPS enabled
    if(true)
    {

        double latitude = getLatitude();
        double longitude = getLongitude();
        Geocoder gc=new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
        try 
        {
            stAdd="";
            List<Address> list= gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 2);

            Address a= list.get(0);

            for(int i=0;i<=a.getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
            {
                    stAdd=stAdd+"\n "+a.getAddressLine(i);
            }
            stAdd=stAdd+" "+a.getLocality()+"\n"+a.getFeatureName();

        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    // \n is for new line
        CharSequence d = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", new Date());
        currentTime= d.toString();
       Log.d("currentTime",currentTime);

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     // get IMEI
     imei = tm.getDeviceId();
     // get SimSerialNumber
   simSerialNumber = tm.getSimSerialNumber();




    }

    else
    {
        /* can't get location
        GPS or Network is not enabled
        Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings*/
        showSettingsAlert();
    }

    }

public void passing()
{
      SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

       request.addProperty("strIMEINumber",imei);
       request.addProperty("strSIMNumber",simSerialNumber);
       //request.addProperty("strAddress","Rajasthan 400031");
       request.addProperty("strAddress",stAdd);
       request.addProperty("strTime",currentTime);




           SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
           envelope.dotNet = true;
           envelope.encodingStyle=SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
           envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
           System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

            try 
            {
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                //SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                resultData= result.toString();              
                //editText.setText(resultData);
                Log.d("response", resultData);
            }
           catch (Exception e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                Log.d("My Error", ""+e.getMessage());

            }




    } 

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null)
{
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
}
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude()
{
    if(location != null)
{
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
}

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude()
{
    if(location != null)
{
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
}

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() 
{
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will launch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
});

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
{
        dialog.cancel();
}
});

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
{
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
{
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
{
}



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
{
    return null;
}
}
```

MyReceiver.java

```
    package com.example.meragps;

    package com.example.meragps;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


     public static final String TAG = "com.example.meragps";
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // just make sure we are getting the right intent (better safe than sorry)
      /*if( "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) 
      {
       ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
       LocationLoggerServiceManager.class.getName());
       ComponentName service = context.startService(new Intent().setComponent(comp));
       if (null == service){
        // something really wrong here
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not start service " + comp.toString());
       }
      } else {
       Log.e(TAG, "Received unexpected intent " + intent.toString());   
      }*/
         try
         { 
             Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, GPSTracker.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);     
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             Log.e("My Service Error",e.getMessage());
         }


    }



    }
```

MeraGPS Manifest.xml

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.meragps"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" /> 
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
        <application
    android:allowBackup="true">


   <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" 
     android:enabled="true" 
     android:exported="false"
     android:label="MyReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


  <intent-filter>

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter> 


      </application>

      </manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Service Always Running mode... or else you need to Create BroadCast Reciever.. Then Service will starts when you boot the Device..  [Link for BroadCastReciever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: I have created BroadcastReceiver...but then also its not working.....i have mentioned above about this..

Comment: When you trigger the GPS Track. Its like when the Device Bootsup, you try to call the BroadCast Reciever, Did u check the Log, wht is the status of LogCat.

Comment: forcestopping package com.example.meragps uid=10041

Comment: Am assuming like you are trying call to GPS api when it Boots up on Device, that may be one reason,  On what basis you are trying to send Information to server. According to the Code, When the BootsUp , you call GPSTrack Service. Make sure Before Performing the Operation, check the GPs can able to Proceed. And Alos check the GPS is On in Device.

Comment: yeah i am trying like the way you assuming...first MyReceicer.java will executed and from that GPSTracker.java will be called..I have check that GPS is ON but again its not working...is the above code is right

Comment: Ya... Did u check the Sent Data to Server was success ?. If it Success, the Only Error is beacuse you are trying to send UI reponse from Service with AlertDialog in showSettingsAlert(). just comment UI respose part then try to execute. If you need to Create UI response form BackGround Service you have to Use AsyncTask, in that case ther will not be any more Exception like ANR Exception. Please comment that part try to excute

Comment: One thing I am sure. I got the ANR exception because when I try to send UI repsponse from Background Service. Please put the Log in each function and If Condition, so that you can track from where u get the error. Please put the Log and try to see where the Exception occurs. Mostly exception Occurs in  showSettingsAlert().

Comment: Please check this sample this will help you to resolve the issue. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: So waht you just use Service instead of Activity. Functionality is same. just see the Log where its throwing error. Dont use UI part in Backgroudn Service, then go for AsyncTask.